# .net 4 MemoryCache leak?

Tags: .net, caching, memory, memorycache

I'm using MemoryCache with Sql Dependencies.
I've noticed that when MemoryCache.Set() is used, there is a memory leak if an item is overriden in the collection. Consider the following scenario:

1. Item with key=A is inserted into the cache with a dependency on Table1
2. A new item with the same key=a is re-inserted using .Set(), with a dependency on Table2
3. Table2 has changed in the database.

-> Item key=a was indeed removed from the cache, but its memory is still claimed within the MemoryCache. The memory is only freed when the data for Table1 changes in the database.

Reproduce Code:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    const string cs = @"Data Source=.\sqlexpress;Initial Catalog=TestDB;";
    public Form1()
    {
        SqlDependency.Start(cs);
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    MemoryCache memCache = new MemoryCache("test1", new NameValueCollection { 
        { "pollingInterval", "00:00:03"}});

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var dep1 = GetDep("SELECT ID FROM dbo.Table1");
        var dep2 = GetDep("SELECT ID FROM dbo.Table2");

        var policy = new CacheItemPolicy();
        policy.SlidingExpiration = new TimeSpan(2, 0, 0);
        policy.ChangeMonitors.Add(new SqlChangeMonitor(dep1));

        memCache.Set("a", GetSB(), policy);

        var policy2 = new CacheItemPolicy();
        policy2.SlidingExpiration = new TimeSpan(2, 0, 0);
        policy2.ChangeMonitors.Add(new SqlChangeMonitor(dep2));

        memCache.Set("a", GetSB(), policy2);
    }

    private object GetSB()
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(100000000);
        for (var i = 0; i < sb.Capacity; i++)
        {
            sb.Append("1");
        }
        return sb.ToString();
    }

    private static SqlDependency GetDep(string sql)
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(cs);
        var cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, con);
        SqlDependency dep = new SqlDependency(cmd);
        con.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        con.Close();
        return dep;
    }

    private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        GC.Collect();
        GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
        MessageBox.Show("Total Memory Usage = " + GC.GetTotalMemory(true).ToString());
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        bool exists = memCache.Get("a") != null;
        MessageBox.Show("Value exits -> " + exists);
    }
}
```

To use the code, hit Button2 to initialize, then change Table2's data in the database. use Button3 to see available memory.

Answer (score 0):

Probably answering it after a long time.

public override object Remove(string key, string regionName = null);

You should remove the older key before you insert/replace the cached data.